# Confusion about theming and version - Shoreditch?

Tags: theme, shoreditch

I need some advice on the theming of my instance of CiviCRM.  I have done some research and have seen this theme and I'm not sure of the following

1. Is it version based?
2. Is it CMS based - depending on the CMS you are using?
3. Or is it a setting inside CiviCRM - I am currently using 5.25.0

[image: Is this Shoreditch?]

I'm looking to move from the before to after.

Thanks in advance for the advice,

E
:

Answer (score 1):

The system requirements are listed at https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.shoreditch#requirements. It's an extension you would need to install.

Comment: As Demerit has highlighted, its a theme. If you're running CiviCRM on Wordpress then you can checkout one of our recent CiviCRM TV episodes to find out how to install/enable it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fIw1ovN_-I